# Performance Counters against remote server and network usage with c#

Tags: c#, remote-server, performancecounter

I've implemented succesfully Performance Counters on my c# application.
My objective is to monitor a remote server every five minutes and collect data.
I've used the classic approach as shown below:

```
using (PerformanceCounter myCounter = new PerformanceCounter(myCategoryName, myCounterName, myInstanceName, myRemoteMachine)){
             myCounter.NextValue();
}
```

So, every five minutes, I read some classic counters(not custom counters) from a remote server after doing a **user impersonation**.

It's all fine. The application performs well.
But one day, I decided to use Wireshark to do some network sniffing and I noticed a network traffic **from 10 to 200 Megabytes**! This is the traffic incoming from the remote server (remote port 445).

Tryed with different servers and different counters. In theory, **when I read a performance counter I expect, more or less, to read a float value**.

Well, here are some questions.

**Why there is a lot of traffic**? I'm asking for a simple float value!

**What is the better approach with Performace counters for a remote polling scenario**? Do I have to keep the PerformanceCounter object opened or I have to close it each time?

**Why this strange behaviour**? I’ve done some investigation with Wireshark. Sometimes the network traffic(incoming from the remote server) for a call is about 4-10 kB (I expect that size, it's a float!), sometimes 400 - 800 kB or more.

I know that Performance Counters monitoring is not lightweight like SNMP, but a polling session could cost about 100 - 200 MB. I think there's something wrong with that... or is it normal?